# chef-client local mode not able to create action on template resource on windows machine

Tags: windows, chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo

I am executing the chef cookbook recipe in local mode, I have placed the template .erb file under cookbooks templates folder.
It giving error  and Chef::Exceptions::CookbookNotFound

attaching execution log

```
PS C:\chef-repo> chef-client -z -r "recipe[my_cookbook::test1]"
Starting Chef Client, version 12.18.31
resolving cookbooks for run list: ["my_cookbook::test1"]
Synchronizing Cookbooks:
  - test (0.1.0)
Installing Cookbook Gems:
Compiling Cookbooks...
Converging 1 resources
Recipe: test::test1
  * template[c:\test-template.txt] action create

    ================================================================================
    Error executing action `create` on resource 'template[c:\test-template.txt]'
    ================================================================================

    Chef::Exceptions::CookbookNotFound
    ----------------------------------
    Cookbook test not found. If you're loading test from another cookbook, make sure you configure the dependency in you
r metadata

    Resource Declaration:
    ---------------------
    # In c:/chef-repo/.chef/local-mode-cache/cache/cookbooks/test/recipes/test1.rb

      1: template "c:\\test-template.txt" do
      2:   source "test-template.txt.erb"
      3:   mode '0755'
      4:   variables({
      5:     test: node['cloud']['public_ipv4']
      6:   })
      7: end

    Compiled Resource:
    ------------------
    # Declared in c:/chef-repo/.chef/local-mode-cache/cache/cookbooks/test/recipes/test1.rb:1:in `from_file'

    template("c:\test-template.txt") do
      action [:create]
      retries 0
      retry_delay 2
      default_guard_interpreter :default
      source "test-template.txt.erb"
      variables {:test=>"1.1.1.1"}
      declared_type :template
      cookbook_name "test"
      recipe_name "test1"
      mode "0755"
      path "c:\\test-template.txt"
    end

    Platform:
    ---------
    x64-mingw32


Running handlers:
[2017-03-08T12:32:35+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
Running handlers complete
[2017-03-08T12:32:35+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated in 05 seconds
[2017-03-08T12:32:35+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to c:/chef-repo/.chef/local-mode-cache/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
[2017-03-08T12:32:35+00:00] FATAL: Please provide the contents of the stacktrace.out file if you file a bug report
[2017-03-08T12:32:35+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::CookbookNotFound: template[c:\test-template.txt] (test::test1 line
1) had an error: Chef::Exceptions::CookbookNotFound: Cookbook test not found. If you're loading test from another cookbo
ok, make sure you configure the dependency in your metadata
```

---

```
test1.rb

template "c:\\test-template.txt" do
 source "test-template.txt.erb"
 mode '0755'
 variables({
   test: node['cloud']['public_ipv4']
 })
end
```

`My chef-repo tree :
C:.
├───.chef
│   └───local-mode-cache
│       └───cache
│           └───cookbooks
│               └───test
│                   ├───attributes
│                   ├───recipes
│                   └───templates
|                    |___test-template.txt.erb
├───cookbooks
│   └───my_cookbook
│       ├───attributes
│       ├───definitions
│       ├───files
│       │   └───default
│       ├───libraries
│       ├───providers
│       ├───recipes
│       ├───resources
│       └───templates
│           └───default
|            |___test-template.txt.erb

├───data_bags
│   └───example
├───environments
├───nodes
└───roles`

Comment: I have added recipe contents as well as tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a guess but here's what I think is wrong:

The template resource looks for a source file in `c:/chef-repo/.chef/local-mode-cache/cache/cookbooks/test/templates/test-template.txt.erb`.

With those log line:

```
resolving cookbooks for run list: ["my_cookbook::test1"]
...
Converging 1 resources
Recipe: test::test1
```

This makes me think taht either:

- Your actual cookbook template is at "c:/chef-repo/.chef/local-mode-cache/cache/cookbooks/my_cookbook/templates/test-template.txt.erb" and your metadata.rb use the wrong `name` attribute.
- You have a typo somewhere in the template name or location while playing with a wrapper cookbook.

Comment: Thanks checked metadata.rb, was having wrong name attribute there.